# Ambiguity in measuring the speeds of galaxies

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, differential-geometry, redshift

People measure the speeds of galaxies via the redshift effect. However, considering our spacetime as a non-flat manifold implies that measuring the speeds of any two objects not in the same tangent plane is not well-defined. So, what do we mean by measuring the speed of a certain galaxy relative to the earth?

Answer (score 0):

In our neighborhood as long as the Hubble law holds there exists a linear relation between the speed of galaxies moving away from us and their distance. But if we talk about cosmological distances then indeed we have the ambiguity you are mentioning.

These galaxies are moving away from us (their proper distances are increasing) however its not a speed in the sense of special relativity because in curved spacetime we can define an inertial frame of reference locally but not globally which means not for cosmological distances.

At best one can discuss a "kinematic component of the cosmological redshift" e.g. here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3536